# Error reading SOAP response with LXML

Tags: python, lxml

I have run into a problem when trying to read a Soap response.
It tries to read some element which isn't there.
What could be the problem?

Python: 2.6.6

lxml: 2.2.3.0

My code:

```
from lxml import etree

testFile = open('test.xml', 'r')
tree = etree.iterparse(testFile, tag='{http://host.com/Domain}dataRow')

for event, elem in tree:
    print("ID: " +elem.get('id'))
```

This is the xml I am attempting to read:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:GetDataRows xmlns:ns2="http://host.com/Domain">
            <ns2:dataRow id="1"></ns2:dataRow>
            <ns2:dataRow id="2"></ns2:dataRow>
        </ns2:GetDataRows>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
  for event, elem in tree:
  File "iterparse.pxi", line 515, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:86643)
  File "parser.pxi", line 576, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64260)
  lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in lxml:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1185701